# Array stack struct crashes with EXC_BAD_INTRUCTION on popping

Tags: swift

I am making my first swift structure, a stack:

```
struct stack {
    var Innerarray = [Double]()
    var pointer=0
    mutating func push(val: Double) -> Double {
        self.Innerarray.append( (val))
        pointer+=1
        return val
    }
    mutating func pop() -> Double {
        return Innerarray[self.pointer]
    }
    init() {
        self.push(0)
    }
}
```

When a do:

```
var test = stack()
test.push(1)
```

it works. But when I do:

```
test.pop()
```

I get a rather cryptic error message:

> Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

Comment: What does the console say (hint hint)?

Comment: Please conform to the recommended naming convention: uppercase for classes and structs -> `Stack`, lowercase (and camel case) for variables -> `innerArray`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an array index out of range.  You need to decrement `pointer` before using it to index your inner array.

```
mutating func pop() -> Double {
    pointer -= 1
    return Innerarray[self.pointer]
}
```

You also should consider what to do when your array is empty.  Perhaps `pop` should return a `Double?` and return `nil` if the stack is empty.

You should also remove the last element from your inner array, or your next `push` won't work correctly.  The array method `removeLast()` could come in handy as it removes the last item from an array and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must use a pointer manually for some reason then you should get minus one when you return it (or set the initial pointer to be -1) since array indexing starts from zero.

```
return Innerarray[self.pointer - 1]
```

And actually you can use .last to return last element instead using a manual pointer:

```
return Innerarray.last!
```